# Push-Pull Faucet Screw won’t turn much

Tags: plumbing, shower, faucet

I am trying to replace my push-pull faucet because it doesn’t want to stay shut off. The screw in the center only turns a little to the right and little to left. How do get this screw out?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Pictures will help us to see what you see.